# Disable touchpad in init script

Tags: debian, startup, init-script, touchpad

I created a script to disable the touchpad in my computer. It works ok when I run it in a terminal. I did some work to make it start at startup because I wanted the touchpad to be disabled permanently, but the script did not work at startup. The touchpad was still enabled after startup. This is my configuration:

```
root@debian:/etc# cat /etc/init.d/touchpadOff 
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          touchpadOff
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
synclient TouchpadOff=1
root@debian:/etc# ls -l `find -name *touchpadOff` 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 345 gru  8 02:26 ./init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 01:35 ./rc0.d/K01touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 01:35 ./rc1.d/K01touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 02:26 ./rc2.d/S03touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 02:26 ./rc3.d/S03touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 02:26 ./rc4.d/S03touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 02:26 ./rc5.d/S03touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 gru  8 01:35 ./rc6.d/K01touchpadOff -> ../init.d/touchpadOff
root@debian:/etc#
```

How to make it work at startup in my Debian Jessie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two choices:

1. Don't load the driver of touchpad into kernel, so `echo blacklist [yourdriver] > /etc/modprobe.d/nomouse`. Then do a reboot, or manually remove it: `rmmod [driver]`.
2. synclient only runs after you started X, so put this `synclient` command to `~/.xinitrc` or to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` or make it one of the startup/autostart applications in your desktop environment.

Comment: I tried the first way and did not succeed. Tried for _psmouse_ and _synaptics_. Then changed the filename to nomouse.conf. Nothing helped. The module of _psmouse_ is listed in lsmod command output. Maybe this is not the name of my touchpad driver. The computer is Thinkpad T500. So I start to try the second method.

Comment: I forgot to mention this rule is activated during booting. For manually remove module without reboot use the `rmmod` command. One more thing: there is no kernel module named `synaptics`, it's called `synaptics_usb` or `synaptics_i2c` (check with `lsmod` command)

Comment: Ok so the command `rmmod psmouse` worked. I also managed the startup blacklist problem. Found on the internet that this should be run to provide a new module blacklist item: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)`. It worked.